# How to do multiple condition in solr join using IN query?

Tags: php, mysql, solr, lucene, search-engine

How Can I Convert Below Mysql to solr?
I have try using solr join to implement it but I don't know how using multiple condition in solr join via IN Query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms
WHERE 
departure_g_date = "2016-08-04T00:00:00Z"
AND returning_g_date = "2016-08-05T00:00:00Z"
AND (room_adults_child = '1-0' OR (room_adults_child = '2-1' AND child_age = 1))
AND hotel_id IN (
                    SELECT hotel_id 
                    FROM rooms 
                    WHERE 
                        departure_g_date = "2016-08-04T00:00:00Z"
                        AND returning_g_date = "2016-08-05T00:00:00Z"
                        AND room_adults_child = '1-0'
        )
AND hotel_id IN (
                    SELECT hotel_id 
                    FROM rooms
                    WHERE 
                        departure_g_date = "2016-08-04T00:00:00Z"
                        AND returning_g_date = "2016-08-05T00:00:00Z"
                        AND room_adults_child = '2-1'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot! Solr is not a relational database and is not designed to match your structure directly. Instead it is designed to find things easier. So, you have to think backwards from what you are trying to find and map your database to that.

In your case, the granularity seems to be some sort of availability. So, perhaps that becomes your Solr document with hotelId, RoomId, RoomType, DateAvailable (single day). Then you basically look for all rooms of the right type with DateAvailable falling between your range. Perhaps grouped by RoomId. You would then need to check whether that availability is continuous, either with Solr or perhaps even in the original database.

Comment: this mysql code try to find all hotels that having two types of rooms ( 1 adult with 0 child, and 2 adults whit 1 child) that is available between date range.

Comment: You may find this (quite old) presentation useful to understand why I am suggesting representing a different level of information as Solr object: http://www.slideshare.net/trenaman/personalized-search-on-the-largest-flash-sale-site-in-america (Slide 39 is the punchline)